# JQuery to disable checkbox if another is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have one checkbox that shows a div if the user checks it.  That div contains 2 other checkboxes.  If one of those two checkboxes are checked, I want to disable the first checkbox.  Some hmtl:

```
        <p><input id="noneAboveCheck" type="checkbox" />None of the above</p>
        <div id="noneAbove" class="hidden">
          <p><input id="incarcerated" type="checkbox" /></p>
          <p><input id="support" type="checkbox" />Blah Blah</p>
        </div>
```

And here my jQuery, the toggle for the div works, but not the disabling.  The alert was there for testing and it doesnt show either, so I assume my first line is incorrect:

```
    $('#noneAboveCheck').change(function () {                
      $('#noneAbove').toggle(this.checked);
    }).change();

    if ($('#incarcerated, #support').attr("checked")) {
      alert("hello");
      $('#noneAboveCheck').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#noneAboveCheck').attr('disabled', false);
    }
```

One last thing, I am (unfortunately) still using jQuery 1.4, so I dont think I can use .prop().
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the second chunk of code in a change event:

```
$('#noneAboveCheck').change(function () {
    $('#noneAbove').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();

$('#incarcerated, #support').change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $('#noneAboveCheck').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#noneAboveCheck').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z2bUD/)**

Comment: Should `if ($(this).attr("checked"))` be `if ($('#incarcerated').attr("checked") || $('#support').attr("checked"))`? Checking both lower checkboxes, then unchecking one will enable the first checkbox again.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for this, I should have known to add the change event.  Will mark as accepted asap.

Comment: `if ($(this).attr("checked"))` will only work properly for jquery 1.6+ It's safer to use `.prop()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#noneAboveCheck').change(function () {
    $('#noneAbove').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();

$('#incarcerated, #support').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#noneAboveCheck').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#noneAboveCheck').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/vy6ce/

Answer (score 0):

```
var mainHider = $('#noneAboveCheck');
mainHider.click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#noneAbove').hide();
    } else {
        $('#noneAbove').show();
    }    
});

$('#incarcerated,#support').click(function(){
    if ($('#incarcerated').is(':checked') || $('#support').is(':checked')) {
        mainHider.attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        mainHider.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
```

});

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKW5G/4/)